# Activerecord relation creation via has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I Rails if you have a model Walrus that `has_many :bubbles` (and Bubble `belongs_to :walrus`, you can create a new Bubble that is associated with the Walrus like so:

```
chuckles = Walrus.create
chuckles.bubbles.create
```

But what if Walrus `has_one :bubble`? `chuckles.bubble.create` is a no go (as it is `nil`). How can I do the equivalent without just passing in the Walrus in the `Bubble.create`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For has_many

```
chuckles.bubbles.build
```

For has_one

```
chuckles.build_bubble
```

In your example above, I think you should have been using build. It adds chuckles id to bubble object. Also when chuckles is saved, bubbles will be saved automatically as well